# How to apply a transformation matrix to the plane defined by the origin and normal

Tags: python, numpy, geometry, rotation

I have a plane defined by the origin(point) and normal. I need to apply 4 by 4 transformation matrix to it.  How to do this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a helpful wikipedia [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Examples_in_3D_computer_graphics).

In case where your you are dealing with a three dimensional space, a 4 by 4 transformation matrix is probably a presentation of an affine transformation.
Check [this wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Other_kinds_of_transformations).

to apply this transformation, you would first represent the plane using a 4x1 homogeneous representation (x, y, z, 1), where x, y, and z are the coordinates of a point on the plane, and the last component is 1 to indicate that the vector is a homogeneous vector.
Next, you would multiply this vector by the transformation matrix to obtain a new 4x1 vector, which represents the new position of the plane after the transformation.

the normal vector should not be affected by the translation part of the transformation matrix. This is because a normal vector represents the orientation of a surface and not its position, so it should not be affected by translation. thus the representation of the vector should be (x,y,z,0).
again, you would multiply this vector by the transformation matrix to obtain a new 4x1 vector, which represents the new orientation of the plane after the transformation.

only the top 3 elements of both the resulted vectors describe the new origin and the new normal (in-short the new plane).

This is an example in Python:

```
import numpy as np

# Original plane
o = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1])
n = np.array([0, 0, 1])

# Transformation matrix
T = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 2],
              [0, 1, 0, 3],
              [0, 0, 1, 4],
              [0, 0, 0, 1]])

# Apply transformation to the origin
o_new = T @ o

# Apply transformation to the normal
n_new = T[:3, :3] @ n

print("New origin:", o_new[:3])
print("New normal:", n_new)
```

output :

```
New origin: [2 3 4]
New normal: [0 0 1]
```

Note: `n_new = T[:3, :3] @ n` is the same as if n had its fourth element as 0 and then `n_new = (T @ n)[:3]`

Comment: Thanks. Couldn't the normal be scaled by the transformation? Do we need to normalize it , so it will have a unit length?

Comment: I am not sure of my answer. but i think yes, it feels logical that a transformation would change the norm of a vector, if the norm of the transformation is not equal to 1, it will affect the norm of the vector (in a linear way, if the transformation is 3 by 3, in other words the `norm(new_n) = norm(T[:3, :3])` ). so yes, i think you have to normalize the vector in order to obtain a unit vector.